# Categories for Article in Liferay

Tags: liferay, assets, categories, publisher

I am using Liferay 6.1.0 GA1.

Where I can change Categories that are displayed in
Asset Publisher -> Edit (Article) -> Categorization

where local (defined in group or organization) instead of being global?

Comment: I think those categories can only be defined in `portal.properties` so they are always global

Comment: Not really programming-related. I assume you mean Control Panel / Content (the section that's named after your current site/community/group) / Categories?

Comment: Yes. And I have my local Categories and they are not displayed, while Global Categories in which I'm not interested are.